# what do these words have in common?

Tags: wordplay

Hi can anyone please help me and tell me what these words have in common, I've tried finding the answer online but I can't find it anywhere, any help would be great thanks

Boro
Bow
Fluff
Know
Pickup
Scoff
Shoe
Taut

Answer (score 24):

They all...

> rhyme with words that have different pronunciations of ough.
>  Borough, bough, enough, dough, hiccough (hiccup), cough, through, bought.

Comment: how in the world did you think of this!?

Comment: @JLee Well, the question was asked by 'damo0666', so maybe user2276541 made a deal with the devil...

Comment: what the Jesus?  How in the world...  +1 @DamienH as clearly that's how he got the answer.